# User Control with Input Parameter

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control with property (*.acsx.cs):

```
public partial class controls_PersonAccessStatus : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }   
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Is there some way to pass parameter to this control in *.aspx, something like this

```
<%  foreach (Person p in persons) {  %>
        <uc:PersonAccessStatus ID="PersonAccessStatus" runat="server" Person=p />
<%  } %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can create a property on the UserControl. I typically use it to enable or disable functions of a control. It is simple to assign a value in the aspx.

```
<uc:PersonAccessStatus ID="PersonAccessStatus" runat="server" EnableSomething="true" />
```

I am not sure about the syntax for your example as I usually keep code out of the aspx, so I would do the looping in the code.

```
foreach (Person p in persons)
{
    control = LoadControl("~/App_Controls/PersonAccessStatus.ascx") 
        as PersonAccessStatus;

    control.Person = p;

    SomeContainer.Controls.Add(control);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you g. You really helped me although I have not found more elegant solution. From *.aspx side it looks so:

```
<%foreach (Person p in persons) 
  {          
    controls_PersonAccessStatus control = LoadControl("~/App_Controls/PersonAccessStatus.ascx") as controls_PersonAccessStatus;
    control.Person = p;  %>
    <%=RenderControl(control) %>      
<%}%>
```

Where RenderControl ia a helper function:

```
public string RenderControl(Control ctrl)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

    ctrl.RenderControl(hw);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the parameter and functions must be declared with `<%= this.ID %>` in the asp user control to use it more than one time.

For example:

```
var ii<%= this.ID %> = 0;
```

or

```
function load_2v<%= this.ID %> ()
{
    var BI1 = document.getElementById("<%= Li1.ClientID %>");
    var BI2 = document.getElementById("<%= Li2.ClientID %>");
    switch (ii<%= this.ID %>) {
```