# add xaml user control with parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, constructor, user-controls

I have a Usercontrol called `TransactionTypeEditor`
It is beeing used to create and modify transactiontypes as well as their filters.

The parent UI element is a `TabItem`:

```
<TabItem Header="TransactionType" x:Name="TransactionTypeEditor_Tab">
    <!-- TransactionTypeEditor -->
    <transActionTypeNamespace:TransactionTypeEditor></transActionTypeNamespace:TransactionTypeEditor>
</TabItem>
```

The `TransactionTypeEditor` has a parameter in code which is required for some application logic in `TransactionTypeEditor.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class TransactionTypeEditor : UserControl
{
    public TransactionTypeEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    string[] AvailableFields;
    /* ... logic ... */
}
```

How can I pass this parameter `AvailableFields` from its parent to `TransactionTypeEditor` at creation time in xaml?
If I add the parameter to the constructor such as the following, my application will not compile:

```
public TransactionTypeEditor(string[] availableFields)
{
    AvailableFields = availableFields
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

One solution would be to add `TransactionTypeEditor` to it's parent via application logic such as:

```
public parent(string[] availableFields)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TransactionTypeEditor tEditor = new TransactionTypeEditor(availableFields);
    this.TransactionTypeEditor_Tab.Children.Add(tEditor);
}
```

This workaround leads to the issue that the xaml preview will not be loaded, but it will run fine.

I think I have found similar questions such as the following but have not been able to  conclude anything from their answers:
[User Control with Input Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079705/user-control-with-input-parameter)

Comment: Declare AvailableFields as dependency property and assign a Binding in XAML. Initialize the TransactionTypeEditor in the PropertyChangedCallback of the dependency property.

Answer (score 0):

with the help of Clemens suggestion as well as the microsoft documentation about Dependency Properties
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-properties-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0

and this stack overflow question about bindings:
[WPF Binding to local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481130/wpf-binding-to-local-variable/1483837)

I came up with this:

Add an extension property to the user control `TransactionTypeEditor.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class TransactionTypeEditor : UserControl
{
    // register dep. property
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AvailableFields_Property = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "AvailableFields", typeof(string[]), typeof(TransactionTypeEditor)
    );

    public TransactionTypeEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // property
    public string[] AvailableFields
    {
        get => (string[])GetValue(AvailableFields_Property);
        set => SetValue(AvailableFields_Property, value);
    }

    /* ... logic ... */
}
```

in the parent's xaml, add the user control with the property:

```
<TabItem Header="TransactionType" x:Name="TransactionTypeEditor_Tab">
    <!-- TransactionTypeEditor -->
    <transActionTypeNamespace:TransactionTypeEditor AvailableFields="{Binding AvailableFields}"></transActionTypeNamespace:TransactionTypeEditor>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: You should pass PropertyMetadata as fourth parameter to DependencyProperty.Register in order to add a PropertyChangedCallback by which you would react on changes of the property and initialize a TransactionTypeEditor instance. See e.g. this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28302378/1136211